# Google Oauth fails with Powershell Invoke-RestMethod while works with Invoke-Webrequest

Tags: powershell, rest, google-oauth

while experimenting Google Oauth authentication, I have some issues when using Invoke-RestMethod in place of Invoke-WebRequest, which is working.
See the samples below. What's wrong with Invoke-RestMethod?
No wonder why Microsoft is using Invoke-WebRequest in the [official documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/advertising/scripts/examples/authenticating-with-google-services#option3)... :-)

### Invoke-WebRequest

```
$Global:Token_uri = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token";
$scopes = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary.readonly.appcreateddata https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary.appendonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary.sharing";
$redirect_uri = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";
$grant = "authorization_code";
# Launch browser to start initial authentication
Start-Process "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?client_id=$Global:ClientId&scope=$([string]::Join("%20", $scopes))&access_type=offline&response_type=code&redirect_uri=$redirect_uri";
$code = Read-Host "Please enter Google authentication code"   
$body = "client_id=$Global:ClientId&client_secret=$Global:CSecret&redirect_uri=$redirect_uri&code=$code&grant_type=authorization_code"   
    
# This works
$response = Invoke-WebRequest https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token -ContentType application/x-www-form-urlencoded -Method POST -Body $body
```

### Invoke-RestMethod

```
$Global:Token_uri = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token";
$scopes = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary.readonly.appcreateddata https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary.appendonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photoslibrary.sharing";
$redirect_uri = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";
$grant = "authorization_code";    
# Launch browser to start initial authentication
Start-Process "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?client_id=$Global:ClientId&scope=$([string]::Join("%20", $scopes))&access_type=offline&response_type=code&redirect_uri=$redirect_uri";
$code = Read-Host "Please enter Google authentication code"

$body = @{
    code = $code;
    client_id = $Global:ClientId;
    client_secret = $Global:CSecret;
    redirect_uri = $redirect_uri;
    grant_type = $grant;
};

# throws 400
$response  = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $Global:Token_uri -Method POST -Body $body -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
```

Comment: As an aside: Your `[string]::Join("%20", ...)` call has no effect, because `$scopes` isn't an _array_ (also: `'foo', 'bar' -join '%20'` would be more PowerShell-idiomatic).

Comment: Thanks! `$scopes` used to be an array, but was changed subsequently to space separated string! Any clues on the issue? There must be a malformed request somehow

Comment: You do your body differently in-between the two... They look the same at first glance but just to be sure, add a `-Verbose` flag to your two WebRequest / Restmethod so you can see the query body for both request. Make sure it is identical... I suspect there might be a discrepancy between the two.

Comment: Yes, this is by design.

Comment: Not much info using `-verbose` Invoke-WebRequest shows `VERBOSE: POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token with -1-byte payload
VERBOSE: received -1-byte response of content type application/json; charset=utf-8`
while Invoke-RestMethod shows `VERBOSE: POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token with -1-byte payload`

Comment: Sage has a point, the webrequest is a single string where the restmethod is a hash table. Have you tried your string version for irm or vice versa?

Comment: I have tested using the body from Invoke-WebRequest into Invoke-RestMethod, throws 400

Comment: Hashtable usage is by design in Invoke-RestMethod. See this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7.2#example-2--run-a-post-request

Comment: You're right, @Riccardo. However, `-Verbose` reporting `-1-byte payload` - instead of the actual byte count of the string that the hashtable is converted to behind the scenes - suggests that something is off.